# How to bootstrap data with unknown correlation structure?

Tags: bootstrap, resampling, generalized-estimating-equations

I am interested in how to validly bootstrap data with an unknown correlation structure. Let's say I am bootstrapping in order to obtain inference for some smooth function of the data similar to a sample mean.

I found an authoritative review paper ([1](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2007.00593.x)) and several papers discussing bootstrap approximations to GEE ([2](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~chengg/Bootstrap_GEE.pdf), [3](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3491908/)), and of course there is a large literature on bootstrapping time series data, etc. However, these approaches seem to assume a *known* correlation structure or at least that there are known clusters (e.g., subjects each with repeated observations), even though GEE does not require this assumption.

**How would I bootstrap if I knew *nothing* about the correlation structure?** Basically I want a bootstrap equivalent to, for example, fitting GEE with the assurance that I still have asymptotic consistency even if I misspecify the covariance structure.

**And what would be the consequences of using the plain-vanilla nonparametric bootstrap** (i.e., resampling individual observations with replacement)? Would this approach be conservative, anticonservative, or indeterminate?

#### References

[1](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2007.00593.x). Field, Christopher A., and Alan H. Welsh. [Bootstrapping clustered data](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2007.00593.x). Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Statistical Methodology) 69.3 (2007): 369-390.

[2](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~chengg/Bootstrap_GEE.pdf). Cheng, Guang, Zhuqing Yu, and Jianhua Z. Huang. [The cluster bootstrap consistency in generalized estimating equations.](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~chengg/Bootstrap_GEE.pdf) Journal of Multivariate Analysis 115 (2013): 33-47.

[3](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3491908/). D'Angelo, Gina M., et al. [Bootstrapping GEE models for fMRI regional connectivity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3491908/). Neuroimage 63.4 (2012): 1890-1900.